# Start-bitstransfer job network limitation ( policy not taken in account )

Tags: windows, networking, file-transfer, windows-server-2008

I'm having issue with BITS transfer

Im lauching job: 
Start-BitsTransfer -Source D:\testfile \10.10.20.20\F$\TEST -Asynchro
nous -Priority low

Everything is good so far, job is ongoing etc. Case is only that I need to limit network utilization. 
I found that I there is policy in Administration Network -> Network -> BITS -> Limit maximum network bandwidth.... 
I limited to 32 Kbps and Enabled it. 
**And this setting was not taken in account  -any idea why.** 

I'm running Windows 2008 SP2. I have done gpupdate /force as well as I have restart BITS service and still nothing. I have the same time when transferring 1 Gb file about 40 min no matter if I will put 64 Kbps 32 Kbps or even 0. When 0 is set transfer is ongoing anyway.

Thank all for any feedback

Comment: If you run a GPResult on that machine, does it show your policy is being properly applied?

Comment: Its in french but all is OK Réseau/Service de transfert intelligent en arrière-plan (BITS)
Stratégie Paramètre OSG gagnant 
Bande passante réseau maximale pour les transferts BITS en arrière-plan Activé Stratégie de groupe locale 
Limiter le taux de transfert en arrière-plan (en Kbits/s) à : 5 
De 23h00 
à 1h00 
Toutes les autres fois 
Utiliser toute la bande passante inutilisée disponible Désactivé 
OU 
Limiter le taux de transfert en arrière-plan (en Kbits/s) à : 5